# jQuery: target element added with .html() or .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When I add an element in the DOM using `.html()`, `.append()` or `.appendTo()`, I then don't manage to target the added element.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <em class="button" id="old">old button</em>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var newButton = '<em class="button" id="new">new button</em>'
var oldButton = '<em class="button" id="old">old button</em>'

$('#old').click(function(){
    $('div').html(newButton);
});

$('#new').click(function(){
    $('div').html(oldButton);
});
```

The latter code replaces the original `<em class="button" id="old">old button</em>` with `<em class="button" id="new">new button</em>`, but then I don't manage to target the newly added `#new` with jQuery.

I could not find an explanation on the `.html()` API Documentation, any idea?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdrwm5zn/) you can update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** on dynamically added/changed elements.

```js
var oldButton = '<em class="button" id="old">old button</em>'
var newButton = '<em class="button" id="new">new button</em>'
$(document).on('click', '#old', function(){
    $(this).closest('div').html(newButton);
});
$(document).on('click', '#new', function(){
    $(this).closest('div').html(oldButton);
});
```

```css
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#old { background-color: yellow; }
#new { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <em class="button" id="old">old button</em>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Still reading about *event delegation* to understand why it's needed, but your solution works well.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `#new` element does not exist yet upon creating the click handler, it is not bound properly. A solution that doesnt require re-binding event handlers constantly:

```
$('#old').click(function(){
    $('#old').addClass('hidden');
    $('#new').removeClass('hidden');
});
$('#new').click(function(){
    $('#new').addClass('hidden');
    $('#old').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdrwm5zn/3/) for the accompanying html/css.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as I need to add a lot more elements than only two,  the *event delegation* solution was what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are better ways to achieve what you want (see Renzo Poddighe's answer and Rejith R Krishnan's answer), here is what you need to do: re-bind the click event when you create the new elements.  Also it is a good idea to remove the old event handlers with the [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method.

```
var oldButton = '<em class="button" id="old">old button</em>'
var newButton = '<em class="button" id="new">new button</em>'
function bindOldEvent() {
    $('#old').click(function(){
        $('div').off().html(newButton);
        bindNewEvent();
    });
}

function bindNewEvent() {
    $('#new').click(function(){
        $('div').off().html(oldButton);
        bindOldEvent();
    });
}
bindOldEvent();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mdrwm5zn/2/